# Expand first partition of Harddrive

Tags: partitioning

I cloned my system HDD with `dd` to a new harddrive. It worked very well and i can boot from the new drive. My problem is the following: i can't resize `/dev/sdb1` giving it all the space left on `/dev/sdb5`.

```
/dev/sdb1      2048  52766719  52764672  25.2G Linux filesystem
/dev/sdb2  52766720  53743615    976896   477M EFI System
/dev/sdb3  53743616  54720511    976896   477M BIOS boot
/dev/sdb4  54720512  62531583   7811072   3.7G Linux swap
/dev/sdb5  62533632 468862094 406328463 193.8G Linux filesystem
```

I want to have `/dev/sdb1` all the remaining space of `/dev/sdb5`.

`/dev/sdb5` is empty and should be removed.

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 223.6 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: D5725B1D-2D70-4FC8-A149-0BA1296F8381

Device        Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1      2048  52766719  52764672  25.2G Linux filesystem
/dev/sdb2  52766720  53743615    976896   477M EFI System
/dev/sdb3  53743616  54720511    976896   477M BIOS boot
/dev/sdb4  54720512  62531583   7811072   3.7G Linux swap
/dev/sdb5  62533632 468862094 406328463 193.8G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/sda: 29.8 GiB, 32017047552 bytes, 62533296 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: D5725B1D-2D70-4FC8-A149-0BA1296F8381

Device        Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1      2048 52766719 52764672 25.2G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda2  52766720 53743615   976896  477M EFI System
/dev/sda3  53743616 54720511   976896  477M BIOS boot
/dev/sda4  54720512 62531583  7811072  3.7G Linux swap
```

Comment: @user68186 i'm booting from my old harddrive the new one is not mounted

Comment: Please add the full output of `sudo fdisk -l` (at least for `sdb`) instead of only a part of it, with incomplete output we can't see much.

Comment: @mook767 updated my question

Comment: You cloned a smaller GPT-drive to a bigger drive, so your partition-table backup is in the middle of the disk, that should be repaired first, please take a look [here](https://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/repairing.html). You cannot increase the size of `sdb1`  unless you have unallocated space in it's directly neighborhood which you don't have.

Comment: Normally, you'd just delete /dev/sdb5, move everything right, extend /dev/sdb1... but you have two problems with that... first, you have what appears to be BOTH UEFI and BIOS partitions (same size?), and second, if you move them to the right, your system probably won't boot any more, 'cause the have to be near the front of the disk. Let me try and put together an answer for this...

Comment: How about keeping / sdb1 as is and moving /home into sdb5? To move /home uses rsync- Be sure to use parameters to preserve ownership & permissions 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving I might move swap to end of drive first. And if UEFI booting remove bios_grub partition as it is only required for BIOS boot on gpt partitioned drives. Then adjust size of sdb5 to include all that space. You willneed to use live installer to change or move partitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you'd just delete `/dev/sdb5`, move `/dev/sdb2/3/4` right, resize `/dev/sdb1`... but you have two problems with that... **first**, you have what appears to be BOTH UEFI and BIOS partitions (both the same size?), and **second**, if you move them to the right, your system probably won't boot any more, 'cause they have to be near the front of the disk.

I'd start over.

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted`
- install a fresh GPT partition table on the new HDD (this will wipe the drive).
- use `gparted` **copy/paste** EITHER the UEFI partition OR the BIOS partition to the new HDD
- use `gparted` **copy/paste** the `/dev/sda1` partition to the new HDD as `/dev/sdb2`
- use `gparted` to **resize** that pasted new partition (`/dev/sdb2`) on the new HDD
- create a new /swapfile on `/dev/sdb2` (assuming a current version of Ubuntu)
- edit `/etc/fstab` and change the partition-based swap mount, to the /swapfile style mount

Comment: `UEFI does not impose a restriction on the number or location of System Partitions that can exist on a system.` Source: [UEFI Spec](https://uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/UEFI%202_5.pdf#page=536) chapter 12.3.3 . Moving a bios_boot-partition (if used) is critical though.

Comment: @mook765 from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace) it says "Description: the EFI partition (also called ESP) contains some boot files. It is necessary if the firmware (BIOS) is set up to boot the HDD in EFI mode (which is default on more and more modern, > year 2011 computers). It must be located at the start of a GPT disk, and have a "boot" flag." I think that BIOS/GRUB imposes that restriction.

Comment: It may say that, but it's not true, at least for the ESP. For a bios_boot-partition it is best to be the first partition, if one would move this partition, it would break grub. As far as I know, a bios_boot-partition can be located anywhere, but I can't prove it.

Comment: Thanks for your time putting this togheter. I'll do it the way you suggest!

Answer (score -1):

Have you thought of cloning data (with rsync) from sda1 to sda5 and just change it to boot from that partition?.

You will not merge the 25G of sd, but you can use that eventually for other things, and you won't have to deal with partition resizing/merging.

Also, i will advice you to first create a separate /home partition about 60gb. You can do that resizing sda5 (maybe use sd1 as /home later).

Edit: Thanks to @heynnema for the correction.
This is wrong, [according to this](https://superuser.com/a/643634/612663), it may be the other way.

```
The only downside of this (that i can think of), is that if the drive     is not a SSD, the root partition won't be on the fastest part of the drive (center).
```

Comment: re: "The only downside of this (that i can think of), is that if the drive is not a SSD, the root partition won't be on the fastest part of the drive (center)." This is incorrect... makes no difference SSD/HDD, and the CENTER of the drive is not the fastest part of the drive.

Comment: @heynnema, you're correct, it's possibly the other way around [according to this](https://superuser.com/a/643634/612663)